# Scrollable progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-scrollbar

I'm trying making a scrollable horizontal progress bar.

Therefore I put the progress bar in Horizontal scroll view and set progress bar min width to 1000 (it's double my screen width).

But I still can't scroll the scroll bar...

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.pkg.pkg2.scrollableprogressbar.MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:measureAllChildren="true"
        android:background="#e3ece5">

        <ProgressBar
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:progress="50"
            android:minWidth="1000dp"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: it make little sense to create "scrollable" progress bar.. what do you need it for?

Comment: @pskink I have custom progress bar that extends progressbar, and I have markers on my scrollbar.. do you have any idea how to make it scrollable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your solution with one changes, assign width of horizontalscrollview to wrap_content.
Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:progress="50"
            android:secondaryProgress="100"
            android:minWidth="1000dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I spent a lot of time on the scrollbars tag

Answer (score 0):

Set *layout_width* of HorizontalScrollView to *wrap_content*:

```
...
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...
```